Laravel 11 Axios POST Request to Controller Method Returns 404 Error
I'm facing an issue when trying to execute a POST request from the frontend using Axios to a Laravel controller method. The request URL returns a 404 error as below.
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
My project uses a custom database connection middleware. Below are the detailed configurations and code snippets:
web.php
use App\Http\Controllers\ClientDataController;
use App\Http\Controllers\QueryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RecordingController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', fn() => Inertia::render('Dashboard'))->name('dashboard');

    // Routes that do not need the connection middleware
    Route::get('/clients', [ClientDataController::class, 'index'])->name('client.index');
    Route::get('/clients/create', [ClientDataController::class, 'create'])->name('client.create');
    Route::post('/clients', [ClientDataController::class, 'store'])->name('client.store');
    Route::delete('/clients/{client}', [ClientDataController::class, 'destroy'])->name('clients.destroy');
    Route::post('/set-connection', [ClientDataController::class, 'setConnection'])->name('set-connection');

    // Routes that need the connection middleware
    Route::middleware(['connection'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/clients/{connection}/queries', [ClientDataController::class, 'show'])->name('clients.show');

        // Queries
        Route::get('/queries', [QueryController::class, 'index'])->name('query.index');
        Route::get('/queries/create', [QueryController::class, 'create'])->name('query.create');
        Route::post('/queries/store', [QueryController::class, 'store'])->name('query.store');
        Route::get('/queries/{id}', [QueryController::class, 'show'])->name('query.show');
        Route::get('/queries/{id}/edit', [QueryController::class, 'edit'])->name('query.edit');
        Route::put('/queries/{id}', [QueryController::class, 'update'])->name('query.update');
        Route::delete('/queries/{id}', [QueryController::class, 'destroy'])->name('query.destroy');
        Route::post('/query/verify', [QueryController::class, 'verify'])->name('query.verify');

        // Recordings
        **Route::post('/recordings/execute/{query}', [RecordingController::class, 'recordQueryExecution'])->name('recording-execution');
    });**
});


I'm so confusing why the error only happens in the '/recordings/execute/{query}'
I think the function 'recordQueryExecution' in the RecordingController is fine because when I executed it with query.store or quey.update. It's work.
RecordingController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Query;
use App\Models\Recording;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RecordingController extends Controller
{
    public function recordQueryExecution(Query $query)
    {
        try {
            $result = DB::select($query->query_sql);
            $csvFilePath = $this->generateCsvFile($query->id, $result);

            $recording = new Recording();
            $recording->query_id = $query->id;
            $recording->query_sql = $query->query_sql;
            $recording->csv_file_path = $csvFilePath;
            $recording->updated_by = Auth::id();
            $recording->updated_at = now();
            $recording->status = 'success';
            $recording->save();

            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $recording = new Recording();
            $recording->query_id = $query->id;
            $recording->query_sql = $query->query_sql;
            $recording->updated_by = Auth::id();
            $recording->updated_at = now();
            $recording->status = 'fail';
            $recording->fail_reason = $e->getMessage();
            $recording->save();

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }

    private function generateCsvFile($queryId, $result)
    {
        $csvDir = storage_path("app/public/csv");

        if (!file_exists($csvDir)) {
            mkdir($csvDir, 0777, true);
        }

        $csvFileName = "query_{$queryId}_" . now()->format('Ymd_His') . '.csv';
        $csvFilePath = "{$csvDir}/{$csvFileName}";

        $file = fopen($csvFilePath, 'w');

        if (!empty($result)) {
            fputcsv($file, array_keys((array)$result[0]));
        }

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            fputcsv($file, (array)$row);
        }

        fclose($file);

        return $csvFileName;
    }
}


Axios Request in Show.jsx:
import axios from 'axios';

const runQuery = async (queryId) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`/recordings/execute/${queryId}`);
            if (response.data.success) {
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                console.error("Error running query:", response.data.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error running query:", error);
        }
    };


I'm not sure but maybe it's the reason I used the wrong way to register the middleware.
bootstrap/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(append: [
            \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
            \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Connection::class,
        ]);

        $middleware->alias([
            'connection' => \App\Http\Middleware\Connection::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

Models/Query.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Query extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'query_sql', 'created_by', 'updated_by'];

    public function setConnectionByClient($client)
    {
        $this->setConnection($client);
        return $this;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return DB::connection($this->getConnectionName())->select($this->query_sql);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }

    public function updater()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'updated_by');
    }

    public function outputtings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Outputting::class);
    }

    public function recordings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Recording::class);
    }

    public function schedules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
    }
}

Are there any obvious issues with my routes or controller methods that might be causing this 404 error?
Tried
1.Verified the routes in web.php are correctly set.
2.Confirmed that the recordQueryExecution method works when called directly from QueryController.

What is the actual URL path of the request being made, when you check in the browser dev tools network panel?

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem?

Edit post & share details about Query model.\

your ${queryId} might be null, or such Query model might not exist in the database

Hi @CBroe, the URL_path is http://127.0.0.1:8000/recordings/execute/27 and I confirmed 27 is the query ID.

Hi @NicoHaase I will say it's a JS problem but I'm not sure it is possible I did some wrong code in the PHP...

Hi @Subha Edited and shared

Hi @krisgjika, I checked the **${queryId} ** and it exists in the database. I also use <pre className="text-white">{JSON.stringify(query, null, 2)}</pre> to check the data and I can see the query.id.

Please check your browser's network console for details. Is the request sent out as expected?

have you added a 404 abort in your code?

@NicoHaase I found the error message about Error response: message: 'No query results for model [App\Models\Query] 27
It seems to still be using the default connection, so it can't find query 27. I thought I could skip the connection-changing step when using the middleware.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is that the backend throwning the error? Does it do that based on the data that it should work on?

I added console.error("Error response:", error.response.data); in the Show.jsx
const runQuery = async (queryId) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`/recordings/execute/${queryId}`);
            if (response.data.success) {
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
                console.error("Error running query:", response.data.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error running query:", error);
            console.error("Error response:", error.response.data);
        }
    };

web.php
Route::post('/recordings/execute/{query}', [RecordingController::class, 'recordQueryExecution'])->name('recording-execution');

and get Error response: message: 'No query results for model [App\Models\Query] 27
I think it is because I have multiple connections (database) and recordQueryExecution in the RecordingController.php wasn't executed in the correct connection.
The RecordingController.php still finds the query in the default connection but Show.jsx which belongs to the QueryController.php requested the data in the other connection.
After I added $connection = session('db_connection', config('database.default')); and
DB::setDefaultConnection($connection); in the RecordingController.php to align the connection.
public function recordQueryExecution(Request $request, $queryId)
    {
        $connection = session('db_connection', config('database.default'));
        DB::setDefaultConnection($connection);

        Log::info('Using database connection:', ['connection' => DB::getDefaultConnection()]);
        Log::info('Received query ID:', ['queryId' => $queryId]);

        try {
            $query = Query::findOrFail($queryId);
            Log::info('Executing query for recording:', ['query' => $query->query_sql]);

            $result = DB::select($query->query_sql);
            Log::info('Query executed successfully.');

            $csvFilePath = $this->generateCsvFile($query->id, $result);

            $recording = new Recording();
            $recording->query_id = $query->id;
            $recording->query_sql = $query->query_sql;
            $recording->csv_file_path = $csvFilePath;
            $recording->updated_by = Auth::id();
            $recording->updated_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $recording->status = 'success';
            $recording->save();

            Log::info('Recording saved successfully.');

            $this->outputToGoogleSheets($query, $recording);

            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Error executing query for recording:', ['message' => $e->getMessage(), 'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString()]);

            $recording = new Recording();
            $recording->query_id = $queryId;
            $recording->query_sql = 'N/A';
            $recording->updated_by = Auth::id();
            $recording->updated_at = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $recording->status = 'fail';
            $recording->fail_reason = $e->getMessage();
            $recording->save();

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }

And the error was fixed.

so your Query model DID not exist in the database :]
